# How do I find a contact in my Google Contacts list?

Tags: search, google-contacts

Whenever I type in a name I want to search for, which exists in my list of Google Contacts,  it pulls up a blank card or tells me that no match exists, or nothing has been found.

Any ideas why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: And this happens with all contacts, regardless of the name you are searching for?

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce your findings, if there's no match at all, like contact name: `Jacob` and searching for `Jack`. You will get a hit when you search for `Jac`. Perhaps you can try and _not_ search for an exact match....

Comment: Sometimes, after creating a new contact entry or importing contacts, Google needs a moment to index it. Usually, it's almost instantaneous, but somtimes not. Waiting a bit solved the problem. But in my case, it said that no match exists, no blank card was pulled up.